# Unknown command: 'ogrinspect'

Tags: django, geodjango

I'm getting error when I type "python manage.py ogrinspect"

Error:

> Unknown command: 'ogrinspect'
>   Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Peter

Comment: So... does manage.py help list geodjango commands (e.g. what's listed in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/commands/).  Are you sure you have django.contrib.gis in your installed apps?  Do you have ogr stuff (from libgdal IIRC but it's been a while) installed on your OS

Answer (score 5):

Have you put 'django.contrib.gis' in INSTALLED_APPS?